# firefox bootstrap addon: install event is not executed

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a bootstrapped addon that just sets the new tab url at install to a new value and resets it to the old one when it gets uninstalled.

Here is my bootstrap.js. I think the install function throws an exception because require is not defined, but I'm not sure if the debugger executes the code I write in Scratchpad in the right scope.

I read somewhere that the api is the same for bootstrapped extensions as the with the add-on sdk, so the require should be fine. If this is not the case, could you please direct me to a page that describes the code I can use in the bootstrap.js, I didn't find anything :(

```
function startup(data, reason){

}

function shutdown(data, reason){

}

function install(data, reason){
    var prev_new_tab_url = require("sdk/preferences/service").get("browser.newtab.url");
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;
    var url = data.url("startpage.html");
    require("sdk/preferences/service").set("browser.newtab.url", url);
    var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
    ss.storage.prev_new_tab_url = prev_new_tab_url;
}

function uninstall(data, reason){
    var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
    var prev_new_tab_url = ss.storage.prev_new_tab_url;
    require("sdk/preferences/service").set("browser.newtab.url", prev_new_tab_url);
}
```

Comment: You got a solution here: https://forums.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=22621&sid=4ea13ebd794f85600d6dcbcf6cc590a7 are you still looking for more? Or is this issue closed?

Comment: sorry for the long reaction time - yes, this is closed. Thanks again!

Comment: if you add the answer here too I'll mark it as solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: https://forums.mozilla.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=22621&sid=4ea13ebd794f85600d6dcbcf6cc590a7

> in bootstrap you dont have access to sdk stuff like that. im not sure how to access that stuff.
>
> but i made exactly what you are looking for with localization :D took like 10min :D
>
> https://github.com/NoitForks/l10n/tree/setpref-install-uninstall
>
> note: the quirk that localization files are not available during the uninstall procedure. so i had to move this to shutodwn proc while testing for aReason of ADDON_DISABLE. it makes sense that files are not available in uninstall

---

you asked:

> How do you know the Services.prefs.getCharPref method?

---

i responded:

> I first imported the Services.jsm module then i looked on MDN for what all it had:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FServices.jsm
>
> then i saw `prefs` then it linked to `nsIPrefBranch` and that documented all of it. `nsIPrefBranch2` is deprecated so I knew it wasn't that.
>
> MDN is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Plain bootstrapped add-ons do not automatically get access to the SDK, i.e. there is no `require`.

1. Either use non-SDK stuff exclusively, like `nsIPrefBranch`, `Services.jsm`, etc.
2. Or write an SDK add-on in the first place
3. Or hook up the SDK loader for your add-on yourself. Only instance I know other than SDK add-ons themselves (heh) that does such a thing is [Scriptish](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/blob/0118d671769109dbbdfbbe9e27ce0da3dc07887a/extension/modules/constants.js#L142-L179).